# Issues with changing existing Parse data

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I am working with Parse for the first time in my application, and everything seems to be working well with the exception of when I go to change existing data. I am simply trying to change a string value that I have stored in a column of one of my items.

This is the code I currently have:

```
func sendTimeToParse() {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "ClassName")
        query.whereKey("Name", equalTo: rideNamePassed)
        query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
            } else {
                // The find succeeded.
                let object = PFObject(className: "ClassName")
                object.setValue(self.timeSelected, forKey: "WaitTime")
                object.saveInBackground()

                println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment it just seems to create a new row of data and saves the time to that, however obviously I would like it to change the existing data in whatever row matches the name of the current record.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new `PFObject` with the line `let object = PFObject(className: "ClassName")` instead of using the retrieved object which is given as a parameter.

Simply delete the line `let object = PFObject(className: "ClassName")` and unwrap the received optional. It could look something like the following:

```
func sendTimeToParse() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "ClassName")
    query.whereKey("Name", equalTo: rideNamePassed)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
        } else {
            if let obj = object {
                obj.setValue(self.timeSelected, forKey: "WaitTime")
                obj.saveInBackground()
            }
            println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
        }
    }
}
```